# How do I implement this webapi "call"

Tags: c#, rest, azure, asp.net-web-api

In my UsersApiController class I have a method that lists the users given a group name and I would like to know if its possible (and if yes, how) to call it like "http://myUrl.com/UsersApi/List/GroupA" or maybe "http://myUrl.com/UsersApi/List?group=GroupA".

Notes:

- so far I only have a POST method to "http://myUrl.com/UsersApi". No GET.
- I'm using OWIN to host it on a azure worker role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Your controller would look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<User> List(string userGroup)
{
    var users = //Get your users here
    return users;
}
```

which could be invoked with `http://myUrl.com/UsersApi/List/group1`

Or, a more 'RESTful' way of doing it would be to remove the `List` part of the url and have a `GET` to your UsersApi resource imply that you are getting a list of users:

```
public IEnumerable<User> Get(string userGroup)
{
    var users = //Get your users here
    return users;
}
```

in which case you would invoke it like so:

`http://myurl.com/usersapi/group1`

Comment: works perfectly! tks a lot! also tks for the tip on the "more RESTful way of doing things"! I will consider it!

Answer (score 0):

Google "Consume rest services from c#"  - this is the first link that comes up: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor

but there are plenty of them